# Basic Cisco Switch Recommendation For HSRP WAN Redundancy

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, hsrp

I am going to have to use HSRP for WAN failover with my two routers since a routing protocol is not being offered.  In order to make sure my active router doesn't get out of sync with their active router should any router fail, the best thing I have come up with is two put two trunked switches between my router's and the provider's to make sure if one goes out, the active routers don't get out of sync.

Here is a diagram I found that basically illustrates the setup (So I am talking about the switches between the routers):

[image]
<sub>(source: [ciscoblog.com](http://www.ciscoblog.com/docstore/images/VRRP.jpg))</sub>

Anyways, can anyone recommend the cheapest cisco model for this?  I will want to be able to to have multiple connections between the switches to reduce the risk of split brain, and will need one with solid STP.  Also, I would like it if I can have redundant power from a RPS 2300 for each of them.  I would also be open to Power-Connect options that work with the the dell rps-600 redundant power.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you right -- are you saying you want to put the switches on the outside of your routers (between you and your provider)?  It's been a while since I was in Cisco-land but that doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: Ya, doesn't seem right to me either but it is about my only option left to me that I can think of.  But you understand it correctly.

Comment: The RFC on HSRP states that routing protocols should be used in this situation, but I think this should still work even though it is a hack.

Comment: You should definitely use routing protocols if you have more than one physical link, but I *think* you can get away with HSRP here either way (question for a Cisco expert).  I have something similar in my datacenter setup right now except the middle switches are really a vLAN & the ISP-side is one (HSRP virtual) address

Comment: Soo... I'm guessing I don't really need to tell you this, but here goes! Shopping Questions are (now) Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go for something in the Cisco [3560](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps5528/index.html) series of switches (or [2960](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6406/index.html) series if RPS isn't a priority).  Expected speeds and other requirements (i.e. QoS) would help narrow the selection process down a bit.

Comment: +1 on the QoS, especially if you're doing VOIP.  Re: 2960s, except the 8-port models Cisco claims they support RPS - Was I lied to by a Cisco data sheet? (wouldn't be the first time :)

Comment: I think you are correct about the 2960s RPS, but I would triple check since there are several sub-versions (TC, TT, PC) within that family of switches.  http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps6406/product_data_sheet0900aecd80322c0c.html

Comment: Yeah there's also LanBase vs LanLite (I think the hardware is the same, but I'm not 100% certain).  Only trust it when you see the extra plug on the back :-)

Comment: Ya, no QoS, 3M pipe so don't need Gig at all :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh, OK I see what you're up to - I'm too used to being in the datacenter where the intermediate switches aren't mine :-)

Depending on the speeds you need any switch should work - for relatively cheap Cisco gear 2960 (or 2960G if you want gig) models will work with the RPS2300 and if I remember right they're as STP- and trunk-friendly as anything else Cisco makes, and you can go up in models from there if you want faster forwarding, more features, etc...

Not sure about the Dell PowerConnect stuff, but I imagine the same applies as long as you can do STP and trunks.